# Pandas apply function to groups of columns and indexing

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, multiple-columns

Given a dataframe `df` consisting of multiple columns:

```
Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5   Col6
   4      2      5      3      4      1
   8      3      9      7      4      5
   1      3      6      7      4      7
```

I want to apply a function `func` for a group of columns

```
df.apply(lambda x: func(x[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']]), axis=1)
```

This works fine as expected. However, using

```
df.apply(lambda x: func(x.iloc[:,0:3]), axis=1)
```

I get the following error:

> IndexingError: ('Too many indexers', u'occurred at index 0')

Since I want to automate the function using a loop in groups of three columns I would prefer using **pandas** `iloc` or `ix` as an indexing method.

Can someone please explain this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need remove first `:` in `iloc`, because working with `Series` in `apply`, not with `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: func(x.iloc[0:3]), axis=1))
```

Test:

```
def func(x):
    return x.sum()

print (df.apply(lambda x: func(x[['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3']]), axis=1))
0    11
1    20
2    10
dtype: int64

print (df.apply(lambda x: func(x.iloc[0:3]), axis=1))
0    11
1    20
2    10
dtype: int64
```

---

You can also check it by `print` (print return nothing, so in output are `None`):

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: print(x.iloc[0:3]), axis=1))
dtype: int64
Col1    4
Col2    2
Col3    5
Name: 0, dtype: int64
Col1    8
Col2    3
Col3    9
Name: 1, dtype: int64
Col1    1
Col2    3
Col3    6
Name: 2, dtype: int64
0    None
1    None
2    None
```

Comment: Thank you very much @jezrael. Sorry for asking such a question. Could have thought of this earlier!

Comment: No problem, sorry is not necessary.